# Persistent Date Stamp - write/read to file

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a persistent date stamp by writing it to a text file and then reading it back in each time the page is viewed.

```
// set the date, w/in if statements, but left out for brevity
$cldate = date("m/d/Y");
$data = ('clickdate' => '$cldate');  // trying to set a variable/value pair
 - It's throwing an Error on this !
// Open an existing text file that only has the word "locked" in it.
$fd = fopen("path_to_file/linktrackerlock.txt", 'a') or die("Can't open lock file");
// Write (append) the pair to the text file
fwrite($fd, $data); 
// further down …
// Open the text file again to read from it
$rawdata = fopen("path_to_file/linktrackerlock.txt", 'r');
// Read everything in from the file
$cldata = fread($rawdata, filesize("path_to_file/linktrackerlock.txt"));
fclose($rawdata);
// Echo out just the value of the data pair
echo "<div id='Since'>Clicks Since: " . $cldata['clickdate'] . "</div>";
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Did you test it?  Did it work?  Are you looking for advice on idioms or gotchas?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  Used file_put_contents & if statements to check  various conditions.  Used Marc's initial guidance - finally simplified it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code's fundamentally broken. You're trying to create an array, then write that array out to a file:

```
$data = array('clickdate' => '$cldate');
        ^^^^^---missing
```

Then you have

```
fwrite($fd, $data);
```

But all that will do is write the word `Array` out to your file, **NOT** the contents of the array. You can try it yourself... just do `echo $data` and see what you get.

You could probably make this whole thing a lot simpler with:

```
$now = date("m/d/Y");
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', $now);

$read_back = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');
```

If you do insist on using an array, then you have to serialize or, or use another encoding format, like JSON:

```
$now = date("m/d/Y");
$arr = array('clickdate' => $now);
$encoded = serialize($arr);

file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', $encoded);

$readback = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');
$new_arr = unserialize($readback_encoded);
$new_now = $new_arr['clickdate'];
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Yep - it just appends the word array to the word locked already in it.  Does file_put_contents append something?  I'm using this before this code to put locked in there:   file_put_contents("path_to_file/linktrackerlock.txt", "locked");  What would I need to change to be able to read/write the different things I need to get?, i.e. text "locked" & the date

Comment: there's better mechanisms than a file for locking things. doing it yourself is not a particularly good idea. unreliable/racy. use native mechanisms, like flock() for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = ('clickdate' => '$cldate');
```

needs to be:

```
$data = array('clickdate' => $cldate);
```

Additionally, you are required to pass a string to an `fwrite` statement, so there is no need to create an array:

```
$cldate = date("m/d/Y");
if($fd = fopen("path_to_file/linktrackerlock.txt", 'a')){
    fwrite($fd, $cldate); 
    fclose($fd);
}else{
    die("Can't open lock file");
}
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, see question above